# Repeated calls of Chart.SetSourceData give error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a problem with an application that was created in Excel 2003 in my company. The application retrieves data from a source and updates a Chart using the `SetSourceData` in a VBA routine passing a Range containing the cells where the relevant data is written.

The application runs just fine in Office 2003, but when the application is executed in Office 2010 it gives this error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'SetSourceData' of object'_Chart' failed.

I have created a `For` loop in a simple Excel file in Office 2010 and depending on the number of columns passed in the Range to the Chart the error will come up sooner or later. The more columns passed in the Range the sooner it will come up. I guess this has to be related with the number of series in the Chart(more columns more series).

Is this some sort of mechanism/buffer in the Chart Object or Series implemented in Office 2010 that did not exist in Office 2003? The same `For` loop never shows a problem when it is run in Office 2003 and I am not sure how to solve this problem.

So far I have only been able to delete all the Series controlling the Error with a Goto instruction to delete all the series in the SeriesCollection using a `For Each` loop to select all the objects in the SeriesCollection of the Chart. If I do this and resume the execution of the application when I pass the Range again all the data is painted in the Chart Object properly.

**Example to reproduce the error.** The following code is to be put in a VBA module in a new Excel 2010 workbook. Run the Sub `setDataChart` and the application will run until the error message is displayed.

```
    Sub setDataChart()
    Call createAColValues
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:FA6"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
    With ActiveChart.Parent
         .Height = 325
         .Width = 900
         .Top = 120
         .Left = 10
    End With
    Call updateValues
    Call sendData
End Sub

    Sub sendData()
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

    'On Error GoTo delSeries:
    For i = 0 To 1000
        cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1:FA6"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    Next i
End Sub

Sub createAColValues()
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:A6").Select
End Sub

Sub updateValues()
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RANDBETWEEN(0,10)"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B1:B6").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:FA6"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B1:FA6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It fails after 209 iterations; I don't know why. However, if I delete all series at the start of each iteration (using e.g. `For j = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1 : cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Delete : Next j`) then it works fine.

Comment: Hi Jean-François, if you change the number of series it will fail at a different number of iterations, the bigger the number of series the sooner it will fail. I was just curious about why the same object and same code produce different results in different versions of Office. I guess I will have to control the Error and proceed to delete the series in the Chart using your code and resume the execution of the code after the series are deleted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The Excel charting engine was totally rebuilt for Excel 2007 and this one has been in use ever since. There were lots of changes, most good, a few bad. Also many little behaviors in VBA are different. You could ask why something is, and nobody really knows other than to cite the updated charting engine. If you can get a workaround for any of your issues, like the one Jean-François posted, run with it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jon, I guess I will have to stick to the workaround suggested by Jean-François to continue using the application with the latest versions of MS Office.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This doesn't address why the error occurs. This is a workaround.

Before calling `SetSourceData`, delete all the existing series currently in the chart, and the code will run as expected.

```
For j = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1 
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Delete
Next j
```

I'm not sure why the error occurs in the first place, but this makes it go away.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jean-François. Unfortunately I haven't found any information about this problem with the Chart/Series so far. I will try to investigate a bit further about this issue and use your proposed solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to define a named range for the data that's defined using the `Offset` formula and appropriate reference cells. This requires the data to be contiguous, not change the initial row & column it begins in, and for you to setup at least one reference formula (`=COUNTA()` on the column/row containing the data) that can be used to set the height/width of the offset range.

Otherwise a very handy little work around to take this out of macros and put it in worksheet logic.